# MySQL - find company who invented most patents in a single year with a single query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in my databsae:

companies - (id, company_name)

patents - (id, patent_name, year)

index_table - (company_id, patent_id)

I need to find what company invented the most patents in a single year, what year was it and how many patent it registed on that year. I need to do this using a single query. 
I have been working on this for at least an hour an a half to no use.

Comment: Get the number of patents grouped by year and company. Order this by the count and get the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably could use something along the lines of:

`SELECT company_name, (SELECT count(*) FROM patents, index_table WHERE index_table .patent_id = patents.id AND index_table.company_id = companies.id) FROM companies`

You can use a sub query to grab the information from the patents table and then link it back to the main query where you're pulling a list of companies. That link will mean it only counts for that company